# How do I get the number of bits represented by a BitSet?

Tags: java, bitset

If I run the following code:

```
BitSet test = new BitSet(20);
System.out.println("Bitset size is " + test.size());
System.out.println("Bitset length is " + test.length());
```

I get the output:

```
Bitset size is 64
Bitset length is 0
```

Which makes sense now that I look closer at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) (the former getting the size including implementation overhead and the latter being the last set bit, with all defaulting to false), but is not what I want.

Since the BitSet I actually use can have varying lengths, I want to be able to get back the number of bits represented (ignoring whether they are set). Is there a way to do that (hopefully with a built-in method)?

I realize I could try flipping all the bits and then doing length, or by tracking the variable I use to instantiate the BitSet, but I feel like both would require several lines of comments with my reasons and I was hoping for something a bit more self-documenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BitSet will automatically expand to a size sufficient to represent the highest bit set in it; the initial size is simply a hint as to how many bits you intend to use. So your question as posed makes no sense.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood how it worked. Somehow I missed the first line of the documentation about growing as needed... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing on my Mac and it appears that the BitSet length wants to be a multiple of 64.  So, for your BitSet size of 20, it defaulted to 64.  If you set your size to 65, then you should see a length of 128.  Setting it to 129 should give you 192.  This should give you a way to calculate your 'true' BitSet length.

Answer (score 0):

Bitset internally uses long (64 bits). So you can determine number of bits needed in multiples of this using the size() method.