# Java BitSet with trailing zeros

Tags: java, java-8, bit, bitset

How do I work with BitSet for bit representations ending with 0s?

For example, to represent "10100" in BitSet, I'm doing the following.

```
BitSet bits = new BitSet(5);
bits.set(0);
bits.set(2);
```

Based on the Java Doc,

> length() - Returns the "logical size" of this BitSet: the index of the highest set bit in the BitSet plus one.
>
> size() - Returns the number of bits of space actually in use by this BitSet to represent bit values.

So, for the given example length() returns "3" and size() returns "64" as BitSet internally works with long.

With the given BitSet, how can I determine the actual bits (10100 in this case) in it?

P.S: I'm working on compression techniques and I don't want to use boolean[] to represent it, as each entry in the array can take 1 byte.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of bits represented by a BitSet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371585/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-bits-represented-by-a-bitset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `BitSet`, the zero index is the *least* significative bit. Your example should be:

```
BitSet bits = new BitSet(5);
bits.set(2);
bits.set(4);
```

Now `bits.length()` returns `5`, as expected.

Comment: I was thinking that zero index is the most significant bit. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The terms “least significant bit” and “most significant bit” make only sense, if you try to interpret the bitset as number. If you interpret them as a field of `boolean` values, the index is just an index, and the fact, that `length()` tells you the index of the last `1` bit (or `true` value), doesn’t change. If you clear bit `4`, the length will change.